# select all rows except the four most recent

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a table (news), I try to select all rows except the four most recent. The table have a field news_date (date format) and news_id (autoincremet). The result should be desc.

MySQL version:
5.0

Table structure

```
news_id       (tinyint)  
news_title    (text)  
news_date     (date)
```

I tried this

```
Select *
FROM news AS n
   JOIN
       ( SELECT news_id 
         FROM news 
         ORDER BY news_id       
           LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
       ) AS lim
     ON n.news_id < lim.news_id ;
```

Can anyone help me with this query?

Comment: can you post at least the structure of your table

Answer (score 1):

The `LIMIT` cause allows you to set an offset.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY news_date LIMIT 3,18446744073709551615;
```

The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1). For more info read ['SELECT Syntax' in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: Where exactly does the 18446744073709551615 number come from?

Comment: Search for it in the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

I would tried the following:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM mytable
 ORDER BY news_date DESC, news_id DESC
 LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 3;
```